# Get RecordId from table

Tags: c#, sql, insert, command, executenonquery

I am new to SQL, I have table with `RecordId` that is incremented automatically and is primary key. I would like to get `RecordId` of the row that was inserted into table.
Thanks in advance for help.

```
myCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO " + tableName + " (DateRaised,RaisedBy,WeekNo,Platform,Department,Site,Process, Area,NavErrorNo,RootCauseDescription,Status) " +
    "VALUES ('" + currentDate.ToString(format) + "','" +
    sender + "'," +
    weekNumber + ",'" +
    comboBoxPlatform.SelectedItem + "','" +
    comboBoxDepartment.SelectedItem + "','" +
    comboBoxSite.SelectedItem + "','" +
    comboBoxProcess.SelectedItem + "','" +
    comboBoxArea.SelectedItem + "','" +
    textBoxNavError.Text + "','" +
    textBoxIssue.Text + "','Open')";
//int lastInsertedId = 
myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

`lastInsertedId` should be int from `RecordId` in my table.

Comment: This code is a security hazard. Read about SQL Injection and parameterized queries. Do not use multiple tables with the same structure (as the concatenation of the table name implies).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this **properly** (if this is for **SQL Server** - you weren't very clear on this), I see two options:

**Approach #1** - using `SCOPE_IDENTITY`

This works well if you're only ever inserting a single row at a time - use something like this:

```
// set up your query using *PARAMETERS** as you **ALWAYS** should! 
// Using SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() to get back the newly inserted "Id"
myCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO dbo.SomeTable (list-of-columns) " +
                        "VALUES (@param1, @param2, @param3, ...., @paramN); " +
                        "SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();";

// set up the parameters and theirs values

object result = myCommand.ExecuteScalar();

if (result != null)
{ 
    int lastInsertedId = Convert.ToInt32(result);
}
```

**Approach #2** - using the `OUTPUT` clause

This works well even if you insert multiple rows at once (typically using a `SELECT` after the `INSERT`):

```
// set up your query using *PARAMETERS** as you **ALWAYS** should! 
// Using SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() to get back the newly inserted "Id"
myCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO dbo.SomeTable (list-of-columns) " +
                        "OUTPUT Inserted.RecordId " + 
                        "VALUES (@param1, @param2, @param3, ...., @paramN); ";

// set up the parameters and theirs values

object result = myCommand.ExecuteScalar();

if (result != null)
{ 
    int lastInsertedId = Convert.ToInt32(result);
}
```

Comment: I will try approach 2, it will take me some time to setup params as i never did it before. Thanks @marc_s

Answer (score 0):

First thing this is not a good idea to call direct SQL statement from code it can cause an issue for SQL injection as @Zohar suggested.
You can either user parametrized query or sp.

Inside sp, you can use

`SELECT @@IDENTITY AS 'Identity';`

after Insert statement, it will return the last auto-incremented value for PK,
then return this value as an output parameter and catch it after `.ExecuteNonQuery();` in C# code.

Comment: could you change my code to proper way it should be written please?

Comment: I would recommend to use **`SCOPE_IDENTITY()`** instead of anything else (like `@@IDENTITY`) to grab the newly inserted identity value. [See this blog post for an explanation as to WHY](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/)

Comment: @marc_s this is what i am looking for but have no idea how to change my code to right practices.

Comment: @PawelG: added a response of my own showing the valid ways of doing this, IMHO

Answer (score -1):

This should do the trick for You

```
private void SelectLast()
        {

            string sqlLast = "SELECT TOP(1) RecordId FROM [YourtableName] ORDER BY 1 DESC";

            Connection.Open();
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlLast, Connection))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                {
                    int insertedID = Convert.ToInt32(cmdAdd.ExecuteScalar());
                    textBoxID.Text = Convert.ToString(insertedID);
                }
                Connection.Close();
            }

        }
```